inconsistent numbers of samples model.fit MultinomialNB
Hello guys I am practicing Naive Bayes but I got an error : ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 4179]
Also, I saw some similar problems but nothing works for me I do not find the issue.
Data set

I already inspect the shape of my X and my Y but they are same length.
X = emailsDataset.drop('target',axis=1)
y = emailsDataset['target']

# Feature Matrix
X.shape = (5572, 1)

# Target Array
y.shape = (5572,)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

print(Xtrain.shape, ytrain.shape)
output: (4179, 1) (4179,)

Here they has same length 4179 and 4179
Making pipeline
model = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(), MultinomialNB())
model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain) # Error line 


ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of
samples: [1, 4179]

Also I notice that my values are inverse, instead of [4179, 1] the console print [1, 4179]

Este problema surge porque el objeto Xtrain que estás pasando al modelo no tiene el formato adecuado. El problema está en cómo definiste X en tu código. Observa esta línea:
X = emailsDataset.drop('target', axis=1)

Aquí, X es un DataFrame que contiene una única columna llamada text, pero en lugar de seleccionar solo esta columna como X, estás dejando X como un DataFrame. Esto hace que el Xtrain resultante sea un DataFrame de una sola columna, lo que puede llevar a que el TfidfVectorizer procese incorrectamente los datos.
Para solucionar este problema, debes asegurarte de que X sea una Serie (no un DataFrame) que contenga solo la columna text:
X = emailsDataset['text']

Esto asegura que Xtrain y ytrain tendrán el mismo número de muestras y que el TfidfVectorizer procesará los datos correctamente.
